# How to send HTTP DELETE Request via C# WebClient?

Tags: c#, android, .net, rest, xamarin

After logging in I can have a token from my remote system. For example the authentication_token is 8JySqFVx_pKx_3nx67AJ
I can log out from terminal via this command

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X DELETE https://sample.com\?authentication_token\=8JySqFVx_pKx_3nx67AJ
```

I need to do it from C#.
I can send POST request like this:

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string baseSiteString = wc.DownloadString("https://sample.com");
        string csrfToken = Regex.Match(baseSiteString, "<meta name=\"csrf-token\" content=\"(.*?)\" />").Groups[1].Value;
        string cookie = wc.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie);
        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
        wc.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-Token", csrfToken);
        wc.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");


        string dataString  =  @"{""user"":{""email"":""sample@sample.com"",""password"":""sample_password""}}";
        byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataString);
        byte[] responseBytes = wc.UploadData(new Uri("https://sample.com/auth.json"), "POST", dataBytes);
        string responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
```

How Can I send DELETE request from C# where authentication_token would be a parameter?

Comment: you can also use `HttpClient` class, see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client for samples

Comment: I solved it. Check answer section.

Answer (score 7):

Solved, I used WebClient.

```
        var wc2 = new WebClient();
        string baseSiteString2 = wc2.DownloadString("https://sample.com");
        string csrfToken2 = Regex.Match(baseSiteString2, "<meta name=\"csrf-token\" content=\"(.*?)\" />").Groups[1].Value;
        string cookie2 = wc2.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

        wc2.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie2);
        wc2.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        wc2.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
        wc2.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-Token", csrfToken2);
        wc2.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");


        string dataString2 = "";// @"{""name"":""Megan"",""regi_number"":4444}";
        byte[] dataBytes2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataString2);
        string finalUrl = "https://sample.com?authentication_token=" + authentication_token;
        byte[] responseBytes2 = wc2.UploadData(new Uri(finalUrl), "DELETE", dataBytes2);
        string responseString2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes2);
        authentication_token = "";
```

Comment: Good one.. only I am not sure @Reza why do we have to say New URI in uploaddata?

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the much simpler `HttpClient` for this job? (Your existing code to post via http could be heavely improved/simplyfied by using the HttpClient)

You could do something like this:

```
private HttpClient GetHttpClient()
{
    // Initialize client with default headers, base address, etc.
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://sample.com");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    // Set some other headers if necessary...

    return httpClient;
}

private async Task DeleteUser(string token)
{
    using (var httpClient = GetHttpClient())
        await httpClient.DeleteAsync("api/users/delete?token=" + token);
}
```

The above is async though, (as everything is in the HttpClient class.  You could however create a synchronous method like this:

```
private void DeleteUser(string token)
{
    using (var httpClient = GetHttpClient())
        httpClient.DeleteAsync("api/users/delete?token=" + token).Result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use a `WebClient` for sending a `DELETE` request. I use a simple `HttpWebRequest` like so:

```
var url = "https://yourwebservice";

var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.Method = "DELETE";
httpRequest.Accept = "*/*";
httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "yourauth";

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
```